# Python Open Replace to Pass Variables for Creating Table in SQL Causing Error "Only ET or Null Statement Legal After DDL"

Tags: python, sql, file, variables, teradata

I'm trying to pass variables into multiple Teradata SQL files. I have several scripts doing this perfectly fine when I don't have a "create table" in the file. When I run the files with the variables hard coded, they run just fine but when I use an open/replace function I get the error "only an et or null statement is legal after a ddl statement".

This tells me that the "Open().Replace()" function is what's causing this. It seems like this is causing python to run the SQL scripts in parallel instead of serial but I don't know how to account for this. I tried to use the open/replace outside of my execute cursor but then it errors due to the variables not being changed. I have some code samples below that are simplified for this question. This is my first time posting a question so if there's a better way for me to do this please feel free to comment so I can make the edits.

test.sql without variable

```js
create multiset volatile table sdates as (Sel caldt, datesk
                                           from dimdates
                                           where day = 'Mon'
                                           and mth = 'Feb');

ins into vartest (Sel caldt, site, sum(sales)
                  from fctsales f
                  join sdates s
                  on f.datesk = s.datesk);
```

python code that works

`query = cur.execute(file = 'test.sql')`

test.sql with variables

```js
create multiset volatile table sdates as (Sel caldt, datesk
                                           from dimdates
                                           where day = 'bbbb'
                                           and mth = 'oooo');

ins into vartest (Sel caldt, site, sum(sales)
                  from fctsales f
                  join sdates s
                  on f.datesk = s.datesk);
```

python code that fails

```js
bbbb = 'Mon'
oooo = 'Feb'


query = cur.execute(open(file = 'test.sql').read().replace('bbbb',bbbb).replace('oooo',oooo))



DatabaseError: (3932, '[25000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-3932)Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.')
```

Edit 1: Added exact error code

Comment: You are trying to execute the CREATE and the SELECT as a single multi-statement request. That's not allowed. You have to execute CREATE VOLATILE in the same session but a separate request. Or you can replace the `sdates` reference in your INSERT with the SELECT subquery in parentheses.

Comment: @Fred Sorry, I missed the semi colons in the SQL statements but have them added now. The query runs when I'm not using the open replace in the execute command. Replacing the VOLATILE table into the SELECT statement would cause a longer run time. I have 12 files and some of them have up to 20 different insert statements so I would have to run that piece multiple times. It was broken out to be more efficient.

Comment: @Fred is correct.  Teradata transactions that contain DDL can contain only one single DDL statement and nothing else.  The problem you are facing is a result of the transaction behaviour.  Getting a bit out of my depth here, but look at the session transaction semaintics defined in your connection and consider manually COMMITing your work after every step.

Comment: It appears that whatever "execute" method you are using examines the input and submits one statement per request when it is reading from a file, but when passed a string it submits the entire string as a single statement. You have to do the CREATE separately.

Comment: @v0rl0n When I run the file without trying to insert variables and have 'Mon' and 'Feb' hard coded, it runs just fine. It's the way the execute command is handled when using the OPEN function

Comment: @Fred you are correct that it is handling the way it executes differently when using the open. The goal is to not have multiple files for each CREATE. I'm trying to figure out a way to get it run the create and insert sequentially instead of in parallel (at least I think that's what's going on here). Worst case scenario I could just do a regex and create a new set of files every time the parameters change but out of morbid curiosity I'm hoping to figure out a solution to this problem that leaves it in one file. I have another file with about 10 CREATE tables that I really don't want broken up

Comment: @Fred i don't know if it makes a difference or not, but the teradata library defaults the connection to TERA. I tried adjusting it to ANSI but that didn't make a difference. I also tried putting in BT and ET around the create as well as adding a COMMIT but none of it seemed to work.

Comment: What's going on is that read() puts the entire file into one string. When you pass a filename, the driver first iterates through the lines in the file and builds a *list* of strings, with one string per statement, then iterates sequentially through the list of statements. See the `SqlScript` method in the `util.py` module within the `teradata` package.

Comment: Note that if you opted to change to the current `teradatasql` driver instead of the old `teradata` driver, you would need to execute individual request strings, not script files or lists of strings. So a better approach might be to put the `SqlScript` logic and iteration through the resulting list in your own code.

Comment: @Fred That's a great idea! Thank you I hadn't even thought of that! I'm looking at 'SqlScript' and trying to wrap my head around how I would use that 'class' I think that using 'sqlsplit' might actually be better? I see 'SqlScript' returns 'sqlsplit' in the 'class' but I don't have a lot of experience with classes to fully understand how that piece is working. Using 'sqlsplit' I can parse out the file into libraries for each ';' and then do the replace on the library and pass the libraries to the 'TD' driver. thoughts?

Comment: SqlScript is an "iterator" class that uses the sqlsplit "generator" method. That encapsulation probably simplifies the cursor class a bit. But yes, you can use that same logic in-line or as a simple function to split things up at execution time and not have to physically split the script files.